# Sci-fi movie on a planet where the sun is powering this flowerlike energy

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I would like to know the title of a 60s era movie where a space ship is stranded on a planet. The crew is challenged by a (from my memory) flower shaped source that taps the light of the sun to power the antagonist, a spherically shaped bio-mechanical device that won't let them take off. They have to use the shadow of the spaceship to keep the plant thing asleep.

Comment: Can you remember anything more about this movie? You might like to have a look at [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions. Any little detail you can remember could help someone to find it for you!